# How to change Visual Studio 2013 license information from MSDN to Visual Studio Professional Online?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

My MSDN license elapsed earlier this year and I have now set up a Visual Studio Professional Online subscription.

If I install Visual Studio 2013 on a fresh computer, I get to log on to Visual Studio Online and it downloads a license that is valid for 32 days, presumably it will refresh every 30 days with a couple of extra days slack.

However, my main computer still has the MSDN license key set up, and I'm worried that it will stop working in the middle of important work and require a full reinstall.

If that's what I have to do, I would like to know this now, when I can do it during downtime, so my question is this:

Is it possible for me to "unregister" my locally installed Visual Studio 2013, so that it forgets completely that it has a license key, and allows me to download the license from Visual Studio Online?

I've tried [the suggestions outlined here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465361/how-to-change-visual-studio-2012-license-key) which involves deleting a registry key and repairing Visual Studio. After this, Visual Studio repairs it right back to having a license key applied.

Comment: Your MSDN license can't actually expire.  You not having rights to use the license is a different question.

Comment: OK, good to know, but I would still like to fix this since my legal and valid license is not the one the software is currently using.

Comment: I believe the only way to resolve the situation is to uninstall it and installion package connected to your Visual Studio Professional Online license.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the license key from the registry after uninstalling VS from the machine, go to the below key in registry and rename/remove it. `[HKCR\Licenses\77550D6B-6352-4E77-9DA3-537419DF564B\04940]`

You can also look for the license info in:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\.....
```

Answer (score -1):

If your MSDN subscription was purchased as a retail subscription not part of any volume licensing or partner program you can continue to use the developer tools after the subscription expired but you do not get any updates or access to the MSDN subscriber downloads.

So if you did have a retail MSDN subscription it is allowed to continue using the tools.

You can read about this in the [MSDN Licensing White Paper](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350). See the section called Perpetual Use Rights for more information.

Comment: The MSDN subscription was part of a Website Spark program. In any case I managed after cleaning up a lot of things to get it to forget the license. Since I can't pinpoint what worked, nor would I recommend yanking out the innards of Visual Studio configuration files like this, I'm not going to attempt to post an answer.